# Scanning notification through WIA

Tags: windows, wia, image-scanner

I've registered to receive WIA notifications for all devices through RegisterEventCallbackInterface for WIA_EVENT_DEVICE_CONNECTED and WIA_EVENT_SCAN_IMAGE events. However I only receive notifications when scanner device is plugged in - I don't receive notification when I scan (for example with mspaint which uses WIA). Am I supposed to receive scanning notifications from applications or only when Scan button is pressed on a device? (I haven't tried the latter since I use a multifunction printer without Scan button). Is there any other way to be notified about successful scans through WIA? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The notification API will just tell you if the button has been pushed. You can register a temporary or permanent (i.e launch an app) handler. If you're trying to scan you need to use Item.Transfer() or CommonDialog.ShowTransfer() from device.Items[1].